# Converting a string in ddMMyyyy format to a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I convert a string in ddMMyyyy format to a DateTime?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try using [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(yourDateString, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

See [Parsing Date and Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3syy57.aspx) and [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)

```
String dateString = "15072008";
String format = "ddMMyyyy";
try {
   DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
}
catch (FormatException) {
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
}
```

Prints:

```
15072008 converts to 7/15/2008 12:00:00 AM.
```

Comment: more specifically, `DateTime.ParseExact()`

Comment: You could also use `TryParseExact()` instead of catching an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily.

Here is example.

```
    String origionalDate = "12/20/2013"; // Format : MM/dd/yyyy
    string origionalFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    string convertInToFormat="dd/MM/yyyy";
    String convertedDate;
    DateTime objDT;

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(origionalDate, origionalFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out objDT) == true)
    {
        convertedDate = objDT.ToString(convertInToFormat);
        Response.Write("<b>Original DateTime Format ( " + origionalFormat + " ) : </b>" + origionalDate);
        Response.Write("<br/>");
        Response.Write("<b>Converted DateTime Format ( " + convertInToFormat + " )  : </b>" + convertedDate);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<b>Not able to parse datetime.</b>");
    }
```

Comment: What about visaversa?